# How to get the width of the title label in UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uinavigationbar

**Question**

How do I dynamically get the width of the `title label` in a `UINavigationBar`? I want the `UILabel's` width, not the width of the `text` inside (the two measurements are usually the same, but different when the text is too long to fit in the label). Keep in mind that the presence of leftBarButtonItem or rightBarButtonItem may decrease the title's width.

**Application**

I want to detect when the `navigation bar's` title text is so long that it becomes truncated. In this case, I would like to display the entire title in a more suitable location. I will use `NSString's sizeWithFont` to compare it with the navigation bar's title label's size to detect this situation.

**Failed Attemps**

1. Get the frame.size.width of `UINavigationBar's` titleView. TitleView is nil. It is only available if you have a custom title view, not the typical textual title.
2. Try to calculate the distance between leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem. These are `UIBarButtonItem`, which do not derive from `UIView`, so they have no frame.

Comment: About your only option would be to dig into the subview structure of the `UINavigationBar` and look for the `UILabel` (or whatever private class may be used).

Comment: are you using custom label for displaying the title? Its possible to get the width of this.

Comment: Set your own label as the title view...

Comment: You could add an IBOutlet to the Label and simply call its frame property. Good luck hope you get a solution